# ViewModel is Null on HTTPPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I am new to MVC and I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now.


When I am posting a form back to the server, the values are always null. I have tried using the model itself, using a collection/list, and the last approach I have tried was using a ViewModel.


The Goal I'm trying to achieve is to mark attendance of events that users are signed up for. I am grabbing the correct Attend info and sending them to the view. I will select the check boxes to update the boolean value Attend.Attended. During debugging I'll put a break point at the beginning of the Post action, and the model, collection/list, ViewModel has been null everytime.


Models:

```
public class Attend
{
  [Key]
  public int AttendID { get; set; }

  public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

  public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

  public Boolean SignedUp { get; set; }

  public Boolean Attended {get; set; }

}

public class Event
{
  [Key]
  public long EventID { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DisplayName("When is this event?")]
  public DateTime DateScheduled { get; set; }

  public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

  [DisplayName("Event Category")]
  public String Category { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Location")]
  public String Location { get; set; }

  public string Comments { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Event Name")]
  public string EventName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [DisplayName("Event Description")]
  public string EventDescription { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Attend> Attends { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Event/Attendance
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Attendance(long id)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = new AttendanceViewModel();

            if (db == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            if (Request.UrlReferrer != null && Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri != null)
                ViewBag.ReferrerUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
            else
                ViewBag.ReferrerUrl = Url.Action("Index");

            model.Attending = db.Attends.ToList();

            ViewBag.myID = id;
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /Event/Attendance
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Attendance(AttendanceViewModel Attending, long id)
    {

       //POST ACTION...
    }
```

View:

```
model CottagesOfHope.ViewModels.AttendanceViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Attendance";
}

<h2>Mark Attendance</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Attendance</legend>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Attendance</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var j in Model.Attending)
                {
                    if (j.Event.EventID == ViewBag.myId)
                    {
                        <tr>
                           <td>@j.User.FirstName @j.User.LastName</td>
                           <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => j.Attended)</td>
                       </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

ViewModel :

```
public class AttendanceViewModel
{
    public virtual List<Attend> Attending { get; set; }
}
```

Like I said before, this was the last approach I took trying to bind the data correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not passing any of the required params to the `BeginForm` method, try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) {...}
```

instead of this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {...}
```

Where `"ControllerName"` is the name of the controller and `"ActionName"` is the name of the controller action. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Without specifying params, the resulting html would look like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post"></form>
```

But when you do specify params, the html will look like this:

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName" method="post"></form>
```

Comment: A classmate and I actually figure it out. Your solution made sense, but it actually didn't help. Even if I didn't input those parameters, it still would've went to that ActionResult. I'm not sure if it was because my HttpGet used the same Action and Controller and it just assumed it. Thank you for you input though.

Answer (score 0):

So there were actually two problems:

1. I was filtering the list in the View when I should've filtered it in the Controller.
2. I read that foreach loops sometimes do not work correctly over lists, and it is recommended to use a for loop and index the List on each iteration.

Updated Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Attendance(ViewModels.AttendanceViewModel a)
    {
        try
        {
        foreach (var j in a.Attending)
        {
            //Needed to filter by EventID here
            Attend attends = db.Attends.Where(e => e.AttendID == j.AttendID).Single();

            attends.Attended = j.Attended;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Event");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
```

Update View:

```
@model CottagesOfHope.ViewModels.AttendanceViewModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Attendance";
 }

<h2>Mark Attendance</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Attendance</legend>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Attendance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Attending.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                       <td>@Model.Attending[i].User.FirstName 
                           @Model.Attending[i].User.LastName</td>
                       <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Attending[i].Attended)</td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Attending[i].AttendID)
                   </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```